# How pass taps outside Qt app window in Android?

Tags: android, c++, qt

I make application on C++/Qt for Android. It has only one QMainWindow and one Activity. But the window is smaller than screen size. It is placed in top left corner. I get events in window but I cannot find the way how pass events to activities visible outside my app window. Looks like window is modal. How can I solve this for Qt application?

Comment: There is nothing in Qt to help you with that. The OS will only send it events which are in the geometry of its window. It may be possible to use the android java apis.

Comment: How? From C++ code I can call functions in application activity. I even can catch broadcasts in this code and process them (at least send to C++ code). But I do not know how make application window modeless or pass events to visible Android screen part. I am familiar with Qt/C++ but not Android APIs.